# How to get SPA navigation working with external framework that uses innerHTML for content

Tags: vue.js, navigation, single-page-application, vue-router

In my Vue.js app, I am using a bootstrap-based framework that generates the html for my [header and a menu nav with links](https://cenw-wscoe.github.io/sgdc-cdts/docs/intranet-en.html#Section_menu_references), which is then inserted into the page by assigning `innerHTML` to a mount point.

But when I use the generated content to navigate, the entire page reloads since the links aren't using `<router-link>`.

One attempt at a fix:
In the Vue app, I assigned a method called `goto` on the `window` object that would perform programmatic router navigation.
I was then able to pass `javascript:window.goto("myPageName");` as the href attribute, but this comes with many undesirable side-effects.

How can I cleanly make the links navigate without reloading the page?

(The framework needs jQuery as a dependency, so that is able to be used in a solution.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) that [watches for subtree changes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31212195/11141271) and adds a custom click handler when it detects the links being added via `.innerHTML`.

With this method, I specify `vue-goto:myPageName` as the `href` attribute, and then the handler will take care of making it an SPA link.

```js
import { router } from "@/router";
import { store } from "@/store";

export const attrib = "vue-goto";
export const prefix = attrib + ":";

function onChange() {
    // find all links matching our custom prefix to which we have not yet added our custom handler
    const links = window.$(`a[href^='${prefix}']`).not(`[${attrib}]`);

    // add custom attribute for us to grab later
    links.attr(attrib, function() {
        // jQuery doesn't like arrow functions
        return window
            .$(this)
            .attr("href")
            .substr(prefix.length)
            .trim();
    });

    // Update href on the link to one that makes sense
    links.attr("href", function() {
        return router.resolve({
            name: window.$(this).attr(attrib), // grab attribute we saved earlier
            params: { lang: store.state.language }, // in our case, our pages are qualified by a language parameter
        }).href;
    });

    // Override default click navigation behaviour to use vue-router programmatic navigation
    links.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent default click
        const routeName = window.$(this).attr(attrib);
        const goto = {
            name: routeName,
            lang: store.state.language,
        };
        router.push(goto).catch(ex => {
            // add catch here so navigation promise errors aren't lost to the void causing headaches later
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
            console.error(
                `Error occurred during navigation from injected [${prefix}${routeName}] link`,
                "\n",
                ex,
            );
        });
    });
}

let observer;
export function init() {
    if (observer) observer.unobserve(document.body);
    observer = new MutationObserver(onChange);
    observer.observe(document.body, {
        characterData: false,
        childList: true,
        subtree: true, // important, we want to see all changes not just at toplevel
        attributes: false,
    });
}
init();
```